# Nestjs, Azure B2C endpoint guard to validate token

Tags: nestjs, passport-jwt, azure-ad-b2c

Good morning everyone,

I wanted to ask this as I am new to Nest.js and haven't found an answer to my problem, I have an application that has the authentication from Azure B2C and I need to guard the endpoints for the application. I am trying to use passport to validate the token and see if the user can use the endpoint or not. But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"
```

So I have been going everywhere with it and I still can't find a solution, tried all the nest.js official documentation and some samples here as well. I might be missing something but sometimes someone who has done this has a clearer insight.

This is the files I used for the implementation of passport, so any pointer or idea is greatly appreciated.

app.module.ts

```
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule
  ]
```

endpoint.guard.ts

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class EndpointGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // Add your custom authentication logic here
    // for example, call super.logIn(request) to establish a session.
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: any) {
    // You can throw an exception based on either "info" or "err" arguments
    if (err || !user) {
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

endpoint.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";

@Injectable()
export class EndpointStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {

  constructor() {
    super({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        ignoreExpiration: false,
        secretOrKey: 'INSERT WEIRD KEY HERE'
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, email: payload.email, idp: payload.idp };
  }
}
```

And the controller only has the @UseGuard(EndpointGuard) decorator to use the guard I created. But I only get this weird error here. Any help or idea is greatly appreciated and thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: You add the `EndpointStrategy` to a `providers` array, right?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I am the dumbest person ever in the world. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EndpointStrategy` was not added to a `providers` array, so the strategy was never registered with passport